# Migrating software RAID 1 to Windows Storage Spaces

Tags: windows-server-2012

2 questions..

1. Can I convert software RAID 1 created in Windows Disk Management, into a Storage Space Mirroring volume? If so, how to do that?
2. is Windows Storage Space at Windows Server 2012 (non R2) stable enough for production server?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No. You need to copy/backup data, destroy mirror disk and create Storage Spaces from scratch.
2. I used to run mirror Storage Spaces in Windows 2012 without issues. But, if I had h/w controller, it would be used.